# Exact sequence of $\mathrm{Ext}$ functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-categories

Let start with definition of $\mathrm{Ext}$ functor . For each abelian group $A$ choose an exact sequence :

$$0 \to R \to F \to A \to 0$$

Here $F$ is free abelian ( hence $R$ ) then the $\mathrm{Ext}(A,B)$ ( $B$ is another abelian group )

$$\mathrm{Ext}(A,B) = \mathrm{coker}(\mathrm{Hom}(F,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}{(R,B}))$$

I have another definition . For each abelian group $B$ choose an exact sequence where $D_{0},D_{1}$ is divisible .

$$0 \to B \to D_{0} \to D_{1} \to 0$$

$$\mathrm{Ext}(A,B) = \mathrm{coker}(\mathrm{Hom}(A,D_{0}) \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,D_{1}))$$

Prove that : 
$a)$ Two definitions above give rise to same group .

$b)$ If $F$ is free abelian group and $D$ is divisible then $\mathrm{Ext}(F,G)=\mathrm{Ext}(A,D)=0$ for any abelian group $A,D$

$c)$ Given an exact sequence $0 \to G' \to G \to G'' \to 0$ then there is an exact sequence :

$$0 \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,G') \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,G) \to \mathrm{Hom}(A,G'') \to \mathrm{Ext}(A,G') \to \mathrm{Ext}(A,G) \to \mathrm{Ext}(A,G'') \to 0$$

Comment: Of course this all follows from the theory of derived functors, but let us see how far we get if we start from the scratch: $b)$ is a trivial consequence of the definition. For $a)$ I would actually do $c)$ first for both definitions (Use the snake lemma) and then $a)$ is an obvious consequence.

Comment: Note that both cases of b) are both trivial for both definitions, i.e. there is no harm in doing b) before a). Because if you want to use c) to show a), you will also need b) :)

Comment: Hey , so what is effect of " divisible " here ? I can't figure out although I understand your idea .

Comment: The effect of divisible is, that $\operatorname{Hom}(-,D)$ is exact if and only if $D$ is divisible.

Comment: Oh , so if we assign to first variable of $\mathrm{Hom}$ then exactness if and only if $D$ is free-abelian ? Is this true ?

Comment: Yes. That is the whole point why the definitions are as they are in a)

Comment: Sorry for ask again . Assume now $c)$ is true then I can't understand why $a)$ is an obvious consequence as you said . And after all can we replace second definition by other definition ? To be more specific , the second definition based on " every group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a divisible group , quotient group of a divisible group still divisible "

Comment: @BangPhamKhoa An Abelian group is injective in the category of Abelian groups iff it's divisible.

Comment: Since the question does not ask to prove that those exact sequences even exist, I thought you would be well aware of this. Indeed any abelian group can be embedded in a divisible/injective abelian group. The proof can be found in any book on homological algebra. On the other hand looking in such a book will definitely spoil you this exercise.

Comment: Why in first definition $F$ is free abelian then apply $Hom( , B)$ we obtain  a short exact sequence . $F$ is free abelian so $F$ is projective but in this case it seems not work